# Is there any software for log file analysis on Windows environment?

Tags: logging, statistics, analytics

Some unkown problems occur on our JavaEE project, I have to deal with few 500mb ~ 600mb size log files which download from linux servers of production environment, and provide real-time infomation support for my colleagues who are now dealing with problems on custom's site.
I never do that before, thus I can only use some simple tools such as Notepad, Editplus, UltraEdit and Excel to do a manual labour analysis. I feel really tired and inefficient，I tryed few software, but they are all used under server environment.
But what I need just a tool which can used as a desktop application.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

News from the future: From all the alternatives one might eventually find with the search terms `log analysis` and `windows`, an interesting one is to use a complete log monitoring pipeline using the [ELK stack](https://www.elastic.co/what-is/elk-stack), namely ElasticSearch, Logstash and Kibana to analyze linux log data, e.g. obtained with Rsyslog. Advantages are the chick dash board and the build-in text analytics search features.

#### References

- [Tutorial on how to monitoring linux logs with Kibana](https://devconnected.com/monitoring-linux-logs-with-kibana-and-rsyslog/)

**Disclaimer:** I am not associated in any kind with [Elastic.co](https://www.elastic.co), I just enjoy using using [NonSQL databases](https://db-engines.com/en/system/Elasticsearch%3BMongoDB).